# Structure a modularized program

Tags: c

I've decided to build a modular program but I fail in implementing this in C. That's my program won't link. I believe that I fail with structuring the dependencies between my files. How is the "proper" way of doing this?

It's a bit of chicken/egg problem. I need to have struct module definied and main.c needs to be able to access module_event and event.c needs to be able to access module_main.

With this example code I get a linker error because of multiple definitions, which I can avoid with using "inline", that is however not something I want to do.

#### event.h

```
#include "main.h"
void event_cmd(void);
module module_event = {.cmd = &event_cmd};
```

#### event.c

```
#include "event.h"
#include "main.h"
void event_cmd(void)
{
 /* */
}
```

#### main.h

```
typedef struct {
     void (* cmd)(void)
} module;

void main_cmd(void);
module module_main = {.cmd = &main_cmd};
```

#### main.c

```
include "main.h"
include "event.h"
void main_cmd(void)
{
 /* */
}
```

Comment: No, that's an include of a c-file and not an header file. I probably should add that I've include guards on all headerfiles already.

Comment: I can't tell what the problem is.  If you have placed `#ifndef` guardchecks around your headers, then I don't see why the above isn't working.  The easiest way around all of this is to avoid circular dependencies.  What does `main.h` have that `event.h` really needs?

Comment: main.h has the struct module that event.h needs. The problem is that not only do I declare module_event (and module_main) but I also define it. I need those to be global variables.

Comment: Your problem comes from the definition of `module_main` in main.h. Take a look at `extern` for how to share globals between modules.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is `module_event` is defined both in `event.c` and `main.c` at global scope. This causes linking issue as the symbol is defined twice and linker doesn't know to which symbol it needs to link to. To resolve -

In event.h

```
extern module module_event;
```

In event.c

```
module module_event = {.cmd = &event_cmd};
```

The important thing here is the definition can either be provided in `event.c` or in `main.c` but not in both.